# Return array index from a lambda but throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, return, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to learn how to use lambdas and in this code I'm trying to get index of some value that is available in the array, but it just return for values 5 and 8 fine and for the other values it keeps throwing `IndexOutOfRangeException`!

```
int[] nums = { 2, 3, 5, 8, 9 };

int rez = nums.Where(i => nums[i] == 2).FirstOrDefault();
Console.WriteLine(rez);
```

Please tell me what would happen to "index" return value while trying to retrieving it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand what the "IndexOutOfRange" execption indicates? It means that the `i` used in `nums[i]` is not a valid index for the `num` array. Ask yourself this: What is the range of valid indexes for your `num` array?

Comment: Yes of course. in this case for 2 should be 0. Is it out?

Comment: Look up the documentation for `Where`. It does not do what you think it does... (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: But shouldn't the "i" evaluates to 0?

Comment: Again, look up the documentation to know what it does. Do **not** insist on wild blind guessing...

Comment: `i` are the elements itself not the index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your lambda expression `(i => nums[i] == 2)`, `i` would represent the number itself not its index so `nums[i]` won't work.

You can simply do this using `Array.IndexOf()`:

```
int rez =  Array.IndexOf(nums, 2);
```

Or if you insist on doing it by Linq (not recommended):

```
int rez = nums.Select((x, i) => new {x, i}).FirstOrDefault(a => a.x == 2).i;
```

Comment: Great Akhkan, could you explain how your Linq works? I mean how for other indexes it work?

Comment: @Ashkan you need to add a condition to .FirstOrDefault(n => n.x == 2). Otherwise, you just get the first element.

Comment: in `(x,i)`, `x` is the item itself and `i` is the index, so the `Select would return: ` [{x =2, i =0}, {x=3, i= 1}, {x=5, i=2}, ...]`, so `FirstOrDefault(a => a.x == 2)` would mean the item from our new collection where it's `x` value is `2`, and after finding its `i` property would be the index. but it is much slower than indexof, so i reccomand using indexof.

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Great, I just need to learn for future use of Linq and Lambda

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani Sure it's great help and tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

`i` in your lambda is an element (and not the index) of the `nums` array.

So, first `i` is equal to 2 (the first element of `nums`). `nums[2] != 2`, so it goes further.

`i` is equal to 3 (the second element of `nums`). `nums[3] != 2`, so it goes further.

Then, `i` is equal to 5 (the third element of `nums`).`nums[5] != 2` but your array has 5 elements and the last element has index 4 (because index is zero based). So, when you tried to access `nums[5]` you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException` expectedly.